# How to set UIButton tap sound in whole app?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, audio

Is there any way to set specific audio file as tap sound in UIButtons across whole iOS app without writing code in individual view?

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to add any code in subclass . so you can subclass UIApplication like :

```
@interface PlaySound : UIApplication

@end

@implementation PlaySound
- (BOOL)sendAction:(SEL)action to:(id)target from:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        //here, play sound
    }
    return [super sendAction:action to:target from:sender forEvent:event];
}
@end
```

and register your own application in `main.m` like:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *appClass = @"PlaySound";
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, appClass, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

then whenever people touches an button control , your custom application will receive this message and play sound. you don't have to write any code in any individual view.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by writing code once in **AppDelegate** file

In *AppDelegate.m* write a class method, like given below

```
+(void)playAlarmSound
{
     NSString *sound_file;

    if ((sound_file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Output" ofType:@"aif"])){

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:sound_file];
    if (audioPlayer)
    {
        [audioPlayer release];
        audioPlayer= nil;
    }
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL]autorelease];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [url release];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops=0;
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [audioPlayer play];

   }
  }
```

In *AppDelegate.h*

```
+(void)playAlarmSound;
```

Now in your class where you want to call the above method write the below line

```
[AppDelegate playAlarmSound];
```

Note:- Import AVFoundation framework

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i prefer to avoid AppDelegate unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, create an 'Observer' class that plays the sound for all buttons are connected to. check [this](https://github.com/YuAo/UIControl-Sound) example.

Answer (score 0):

creating a category is the way to go. answered by [tiguero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997084/tiguero)

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SCLSoundEffect;

typedef enum {
  SCLCLICKSOUND = 0,
  SCLOTHERSOUND,  
} 

SCLSoundCategory;


@interface UIButton (soundEffect)

@property (nonatomic, strong) SCLSoundEffect *buttonSoundEffect;


+ (id) buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType andSound: (SCLSoundCategory)soundCategory;
- (void) playSound;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "UIButton+soundEffect.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import "SCLSoundEffect.h"

static char const * const kButtonSoundEffectKey = "buttonSoundEffect";

@implementation UIButton (soundEffect)

@dynamic buttonSoundEffect;


+ (id) buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType andSound:(SCLSoundCategory) soundCategory;
{
    UIButton *newButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:buttonType];

    NSString *stringToUse = nil;

    switch (soundCategory) {
        case SCLCLICKSOUND:
            stringToUse = @"button_sound.wav";
            break;
        case SCLOTHERSOUND:
            assert(0); // To be defined

        default:
            break;
    }

    [newButton setButtonSoundEffect: [[SCLSoundEffect alloc] initWithSoundNamed:stringToUse]];
    [newButton addTarget:newButton action:@selector(playSound) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    return newButton;
}


- (void) playSound
{
    [self.buttonSoundEffect play];
}


- (SCLSoundEffect *)buttonSoundEffect {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kButtonSoundEffectKey);
}

- (void)setButtonSoundEffect:(SCLSoundEffect *)buttonSoundEffect{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kButtonSoundEffectKey, buttonSoundEffect, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [self setButtonSoundEffect:nil];
}
Now each time I create a button that play some sound I just need to use the following method:

UIButton *mySoundButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom andSound:SCLCLICKSOUND];
```